# Strapi graphql mutation

Tags: graphql, strapi, mutation

I'm using strapi as a headless CMS

I've created a Customer content type and I've installed the graphql plugin.

I'm trying to create a mutation in the graphql playground to create a new Customer

```
mutation createCustomer($username: String!, $email: String, $password: String){
  createCustomer(username: $username, email: $email, password: $password){
    _id username email password
  }
}
```

I'm passing the username etc in the query variables

```
{ "username": "user1" }
{ "email": "User1@test.com" }
{"password":"123456"}
```

I'm getting the error

```
"message": "Unknown argument \"username\" on field \"createCustomer\" of type \"Mutation\".",
```

If I look in the Docs the it looks like.

[image]

How can I write a mutation to create a new Customer

Comment: did you check user permissins?

Comment: Yes, permissions are all set

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that are missing the reference to Customer type in the Query component of the Mutation.

Also, I believe you are missing "input:" & "data:". I know that these are required when using createUser.

By example:

```graphql
mutation createCustomer($username: String!, $email: String, $password: String) {
  createCustomer(
    input: { data: { username: $username, email: $email, password: $password } }
  ) {
    customer {
      id
      username
      email
      password
    }
  }
}
```